# How to set a dynamic objects array property with a list of a different dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I'm passing in 2 dynamic objects into my method. 'injuredParty' has a property called dependents that's an array of dependents that I want to fill with the second dynamic object 'dependent'

Is this possible?

```
public static dynamic MapTrustOnline(DetailedDto detailed, dynamic injuredParty, dynamic dependent) { 

    injuredParty.dependents = new dependent[4];

    for(int i = 0; i <= detailed.dependents.length; i++) {
        var dynDependent = new dependent();
        dynDependent.property1 = detailed.dependents[i].property1;
        dynDependent.property2 = detailed.dependents[i].property2;
        injuredParty.dependents[i] = dynDependent;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can explain the Logic a litte better It can be done using ExpandoObject and IDictionary. 
Specifically, why do we need to pass dynamic dependent in the function? is that required? is that being used anywhere? If we are only creating dynamic object we wouldn't need to pass it in .

Comment: I solved it using generics. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing in the dependent object in the class and then doing this below.

```
        var genDependents = detailedClaim.Matter.MatterData.GeneralDependentDto;
        inj.dependents = new T[genDependents.Count];
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var dep in genDependents) {

            T myObj = new T();
            var birthDateProp = myObj.GetType().GetProperty("birthdate");
            birthDateProp.SetValue(myObj, (DateTime)dep.BirthDate, null);
            inj.dependents[i] = myObj;
            i++;
        }
```